# Angualrjs: isolated scope and nested directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was stuck with the below problem, and finally realized it behaves differently in different versions of Angularjs. Please see the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/CfeNE/4/

What I was expecting is, anything included within a directive with isolated scope only sees the $scope of the directive. In the below example, there are 2 directives nested.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('TestController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.data = {
            type: "abc",
            values: [{name:"aa"}, {name: "bb"}]
        }
}]);   
myApp.directive('directive', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            data: "=",
        },
        restrict: 'E'
    };
});


myApp.directive('subDirective', function () {
    return {    
        template: '<div>Data: {{data}}</div>',
        restrict: 'E'        
    };
});
```

and I am nesting them as

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    <directive data="data.values">
        <sub-directive></sub-directive>
    </directive>
</div>
```

so the `data` as seen by the template of `sub-directive` is `data.values`. This is the behavior if you select `angularJS 1.1.1` in the fiddle (drop down on the left side). But, if I choose version `AngularJS 1.2.1` it sees `data` of the controller scope. Was it an intentional change, any reference to it?.

### Edit:

As @hassassin points out there was a bunch of changes related to this

```
1.2.0 timely-delivery (2013-11-08)
$compile:
don't leak isolate scope state when replaced directive is used multiple times (b5af198f)
correct isolate scope distribution to controllers (3fe4491a)
replaced element has isolate scope (97c7a4e3)
only pass isolate scope to children that belong to the isolate directive (d0efd5ee)
make isolate scope truly isolate (909cabd3, #1924, #2500)
```

But, does transclusion can be used to make this work. Not sure why @allenhwkim fiddle in the comment is not working.
Thanks.

Comment: Played with your fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/CfeNE/5/ http://jsfiddle.net/CfeNE/6/. Element within directive without transclude is new to me.

Comment: Isolate scopes are now actually isolated. Check out this commit: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/909cabd36d779598763cc358979ecd85bb40d4d7